# Camel SQL - Put DataSource to SimpleRegistry in Spring Boot

Tags: apache-camel, datasource, camel-sql

I am using Spring Boot to initiate a camel route that uses Camel-sql to query MySQL DB and call a REST service.

application.properties

```
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=mysql://IP:PORT/abc
db.username=abc
db.password=pwd
```

Application.java

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WlEventNotificationBatchApplication.class, args);

}
```

DataSourceConfig.java

```java
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Value("${db.driver}")
    public String dbDriver;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    public String dbUrl;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    public String dbUserName;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    public String dbPassword;
    @Bean("dataSource")
    public DataSource getConfig() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriver);
        dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUserName);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

WLRouteBuilder.java

```java
@Component
public class WLRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Autowired
    private NotificationConfig notificationConfig;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:eventNotification")
                .to("sql:"+notificationConfig.getSqlQuery()+"?dataSource="+dataSource)
                .process(new RowMapper())
                .log("${body}");

    }
}
```

I see the below error when I run, found out that Camel is unable to find DataSource bean in registry. I am quite not sure how to inject "DataSource" to Registry in Spring Boot using Java DSL.

```
?dataSource=org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource%40765367 due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@765367 of type: javax.sql.DataSource
```

Answer (score 4):

Its the name of the bean that Camel uses in the uri, where you refer to it using the `#` syntax as documented here: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html (referring beans)

So something alike

```
 .to("sql:"+notificationConfig.getSqlQuery()+"?dataSource=#dataSource"
```

Where `dataSource` is the name of the bean that creates the `DataSource`, which you can give another name eg

```
@Bean("myDataSource")
```

And then the Camel SQL endpoint is

```
    .to("sql:"+notificationConfig.getSqlQuery()+"?dataSource=#myDataSource"
```

Comment: Hi Claus, Thanks a lot for your response. Can I ask you one more question.                 from("sql:{{list.sql}}?dataSource=#dataSource")
                        .log("process row ${body}")
                        .end(); and in application.properties file, I have included camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true. Route is executed in infinite until I press CNTRL + C. If I remove camel.springboot.main-run-controller, Camel starts the route and stops the main thread. Is there anyway I can have Camel start, execute the route and stop. Hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Claus, Sorry if I am missing something very simple. I am using Spring Boot for this application. I have tried from("sql:{{list.eventnotification.sql}}?dataSource=#dataSource")
                        .log("process row ${body}")
                        .to("mock:bar"); and added getContext().stop();. Still the route is not stopped because of camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true in application.properties. In a standalone Java app, we start route (camelcontext.start()) and stop it manually. How does it work in Spring Boot? Pls help

Comment: Yeah I think there is a fix in the next 2.18.1 release.

Comment: Is there any work-around I can do, to start, process and stop the route in Spring Boot. My code either runs infinite route loop (camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true) or stops with out executing the route?